# TSQL Seperate rows into follow on action rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to separate into columns the follow on action that has occurred in sequence, so first action, second action, third action. I think I can use the SyncDate to split the follow on actions byt don't know the best way to do this.

I have tied using the row_number function but this does not correctly list the RowNo. I was thinking of using CTE's to split the three actions.

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT  [RM-JOB].[Job-No] [Visit no]

, cast(ard.SyncDate as date) [SyncDate]
, ard.actionref
, ard.FollowUpReq [FOLLOW ON]
, ARD.GeneralComments [FOLLOW ON ACTION]
, ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by [RM-JOB].[Job-No], cast(ard.SyncDate as date), ard.actionref order by ard.actionref, cast(ard.SyncDate as date) desc) AS 'RowNo'
FROM            [CYHSQL01].[TM_FireRiskAssessment].[dbo].[ActionRequiredDetails] ARD right outer JOIN
                [CYHSQL01].[TM_FireRiskAssessment].[dbo].ActionRequired AR ON ARD.ResultId = AR.ResultId inner join
                         [RM-JOB] on AR.JobNo = [RM-JOB].[Job-No]
```

That produces the results below, the below can be considered as the data too.

```
Visit no    SyncDate    actionref   FOLLOW ON   FOLLOW ON ACTION    RowNo
10233639    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1
10233639    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1
10233639    03/10/2019  CP31    No  Have visited all properties. All properties look to be compliant.   1
10233639    03/10/2019  CP31    No  Have visited all properties. All properties look to be compliant.   1
10233639    03/10/2019  CP33    Yes I’m not sure whether roof space is fire resistant. I will arrange for someone to inspect this.  1
10233639    04/10/2019  CP33    Yes I’m not sure whether roof space is fire resistant. I will arrange for someone to inspect this.  2
10233639    04/10/2019  CP33    No  Roofs Ltd will attend on 12/10/19   2
10233649    03/10/2019  CP31    No  All doors are fire compliant.   1
10233649    03/10/2019  CP31    No  All doors are fire compliant.   1
10233649    04/10/2019  CP33    Yes I will arrange for a contractor to carry out the inspection.    2
10233649    04/10/2019  CP33    No  I’ve arranged an appointment with the contractor to attend on 23/10/19  2
10233649    05/10/2019  CP33    Yes I will arrange for a contractor to carry out the inspection.    3
10233649    05/10/2019  CP33    No  I’ve arranged an appointment with the contractor to attend on 23/10/19  3
10233652    04/10/2019  CB8 No  Cardboard box was empty so I removed it from the communal area. 1
10233652    04/10/2019  CB8 No  Cardboard box was empty so I removed it from the communal area. 1
10233652    04/10/2019  CB8 No  Cardboard box was empty so I removed it from the communal area. 1
10233652    05/10/2019  CP32    No  All doors were checked and are fire resistant.  2
10233652    05/10/2019  CP32    No  All doors were checked and are fire resistant.  2
10233652    05/10/2019  CP32    No  All doors were checked and are fire resistant.  2
10233652    06/10/2019  CP33    Yes I will arrange for a contractor to inspect this.    3
10233652    06/10/2019  CP33    No  Contractor has been booked and will attend on 20/10/19  3
10233652    06/10/2019  CP33    Yes I will arrange for a contractor to inspect this.    3
10233652    06/10/2019  CP33    No  Contractor has been booked and will attend on 20/10/19  3
```

Does someone know the nest way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Showing us what your data looks like after your failed attempt doesn't reaklly help us. We need to know what your data looks like **before** your attempt(s), and what you want your results at the end to look like. Please also take the time to format your data; the data we do have is quite a mess and we shouldn't need to guess what column each value belongs in. You would be far better off supplying the same data as DDL and DML statements; however, *readable* tabular formatted `text` for the expected results will be fine.

Comment: Thanks Larnu I didn't know how to format the data. The data apart from the rownumber is how it is.